# How do I reinstall Vista from the recovery partition on a HP Pavilion DV9000?

Tags: windows-vista, system-recovery

I have no any CD for this laptop but I have HP recovery partition there and I need to install Vista back on main partition. 
I do not see any option to boot from recovery partition 
Could anyone please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

When the HP splash screen appears immediately after you turn on the laptop, press "Esc" to change the boot order.  I think there is an option listed in there to boot from the recovery partition.

I have a DV9000, but I think I removed the recovery partition so I'm going by memory.

Comment: That's the main problem - I do not see any option to boot from that partition

Comment: Using Google, some people say you can press F11 to boot to the recovery partition.  Others say you are out of luck if you didn't burn the recovery disks yourself.

Comment: Sorry, F11 does not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a restore cd from here:
[Windows Vista Recovery Disc Download](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/)

**EDIT**
Alternatively, you can create a recovery cd from your machine by using the method found here : ["RECDISC.EXE how to create a recovery/repair cd"](http://www.c4consulting.com.au/soluctions/vista/VISTA%20SOLUCTIONS.htm). This method required a Vista cd, which you might not have. In the past Vista was available from Microsoft for trial download, and is still available from [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/02/05/download-windows-vista-ultimate-full-retail-dvd-media-image-32-bit-and-64-bit-all-editions/).

Comment: I just found out that the direct download link above was replaced by a torrent. I hope that's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot use torrent, otherwise I will have huge roblems. Is there any http link?

Comment: There are 3 alternative download locations in this link : http://www.brothersoft.com/windows-vista-data-recovery-download-63460.html

Comment: Thank you. But these links point to some ntfs-fat-data-recovery utility. I wonder how it could help to reinstal vista rather than recover a deleted file.

Comment: You're right, and the above cd can do lots of things, but not reinstall. If you lack an HP installation cd, you can use a generic vista cd, but it will lack the HP drivers. In the past when having a similar problem with a dell, I've simply gone into the recovery partition and have initiated the reimaging myself. Could you please add the contents of the recovery partition in your post?

Comment: Another comment: Whatever you do, make sure to note your Vista serial number and all other installed products. Also try to keep a way-back solution, maybe by taking an image of you C disk on an external disk (see http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: sorry, too late...

Comment: Here is what on the recovery partition. How to make it run?
\boot\*
\boot\BOOTFIX.BIN
\boot\BOOTSECT.EXE
\boot\ETFSBOOT.COM
\HP\RECOVERY
\HP\RECOVERY\HP
\HP\RECOVERY\MULTI.FLG
\HP\RECOVERY\REIMAGE.FLG
\HP\RECOVERY\RestoreWiz.exe
\HP\RECOVERY\Skin.smf
\preload\BASE.DAT
\preload\BASE.WIM
\preload\CD0
\preload\CSP.DAT
\program files\*
\RECOVERY
\SOURCES\boot.wim
\SOURCES\SOFTTHINKS
\swsetup
\Tools\Flags
\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32

Comment: Does this document help : http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c00608578&product=18703#N1472.
And especially the section "Reinstall the operating system using the advanced recovery options".

Comment: Unfortunately not. It says 'Click Start , click All Programs , select System Recovery  and click PC Recovery' but there is XP installed there, not vista.

Comment: OK, if you're still there : what happens if you launch RestoreWiz.exe?

Comment: It says that something is corrupted (I will give you precise wording later) and stops. Is there any chance to use .wim images to burn a recovery DVD?

Comment: Yes, you can! See this : http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/10/how-to-make-vista-bootable-dvd-with-wim-downloaded-files/