# Black screen after logging in to Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, graphics-card, display

I have the following:

**OS:** Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit *(with SP2)*
**Videocard:** nVidia GeForce 8400M GS

I was having some other issues with my videocard, so I went to nVidia's website and downloaded the latest driver available (260.99).

However, upon restart, the display goes blank as soon as the login process is complete. The login screen displays fine, as well as the security screen, but all I get is a black screen for everything else.

---

**Edit:** I can easily roll back the driver using System Restore, but *that doesn't solve the problem* because the original driver had its own problems.

---

**Second edit:** I am now installing [this](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-win7-winvista-260.63-beta-driver.html) driver to see if that makes any difference.

---

**Third edit:** Okay, that didn't work. I'm going to add a bit more info below and add a bounty to try to get some answers because this is really bugging me:

**Model:** [HP Pavillion dv6757ca](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/ho/WF06b/12139188-78299199-78299212-78299212-78299212-81140084-81563081.html)

[image]

---

**Fourth edit:** I've gotten some very helpful answers and I'm going to start trying some of them now.
*Note: I don't actually have a recovery CD, **but** I do have a recovery partition that I might be able to use.*

---

**Final edit:** Thanks for the wonderful answers everyone. Unfortunately, none of them seemed to work and it looks like this is one of those issues that will have to remain until the next upgrade.

Comment: By some chance is/was a second monitor hooked up that it might now be routing the input to on login

Comment: Is this an nVidia made card or third party using the nVidia chipset?

Comment: @quickcel: No, there was no secondary monitor plugged in during startup, though I have used a secondary monitor in the past. I doubt this was the problem, though, because it was working fine until I restarted.

Comment: @DaveM: I have no idea. I'm guessing that it was, but I don't really know. How can I find out?

Comment: @quickcel: I have a special button on the keyboard that toggles through all of the attached displays. Pushing that button did nothing, so I'm assuming that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: After logging in, press CTRL+SHIFT+ESC and see if the task manager comes up.  If it does, does `explorer.exe` appear in the processes list?

Comment: @TuxRug: Nope, I can't bring up the task manager. When I hit `Ctrl-Alt-Delete` and click 'Task Manager', it freezes and I have to hard-reset the PC.

Comment: i have seen a couple of references to nvidia driver problems that result in this behavior...no solutions yet though

Answer (score 1):

This article might be useful:
[Make User Account Control (UAC) Stop Blacking Out the Screen in Windows 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-user-account-control-uac-stop-blacking-out-the-screen-in-windows-vista/).

The idea is to disable the group policy of "User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation".

As you are on Vista Home, you will need to directly edit the registry. Open regedit and go to:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

Right-click in the right-hand pane and create a new 32-bit DWORD value called `PromptOnSecureDesktop`, setting the value to 0.

The article also offers a [Download DisableSecureDesktop Registry Hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/DisableSecureDesktop.zip).

---

If this doesn't help, and as you mentioned elsewhere that you can get into Safe mode, try scanning for system corruption : [How to Repair Windows 7 System Files with System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

If nothing is found, you next step is 
[How Do I Perform a Startup Repair or Repair Installation of Windows?](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/f/repair-installation-windows.htm).
This will refresh the Windows installation while leaving alone all installed products. Use a boot CD that is compatible with your installed service pack.

If this doesn't work, your next step is to uninstall products that might be responsible for this problem, hoping to find one such product.

The last resort is to reformat the disk and reinstall Windows from scratch. Your computer probably has a restore CD that can restore it to its initial state as when bought.

Comment: Well, it's worth a try. Should I make the registry change in safe mode? (Since obviously I can't change it otherwise.)

Comment: After doing some more reading, all this does is disable the secure desktop - I can't even get the normal desktop to display. Not to mention that following the advice would result in a rather serious security concern.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the secure desktop is displayed rather than the normal one. You can always undo it if it doesn't help.

Comment: If you have tried it and it changes nothing, I have added some more ideas.

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks. I do have a recovery partition, but like most people, I didn't bother making recovery disks :)

Comment: This might help : [How to Create HP Restore Disks](http://www.pctechbytes.com/hp/hp-recovery-cd-creation). To be read carefully.

Comment: @harrymc: Just tried your suggestions, but I'm afraid it didn't work.

Comment: Which ones didn't work, and why?

Comment: If this is a recovery CD problem, see my answer *and comments* [here](http://superuser.com/questions/44164/how-to-reinstall-vista-from-recovery-partition-on-hp-pavilion-dv9000/44172#44172).

Comment: @harrymc: I tried the registry change you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

From [The Back Room Tech](http://thebackroomtech.com/2008/12/30/fix-for-windows-vista-black-screen-of-death-aka-ksod/):

> Here is how to recover from the KSOD
>   (blacK Screen Of Death):
>
> There apparently this a problem
>   related to the Remote Procedure Call
>   service (RPC) running under
>   LocalSystem account instead of NT
>   Authority\NetworkService account.
>
> 1. On the affected machine, boot using the Vista Media and Select “Next” and
>      then in the bottom left you will see
>      “Repair your Computer”; select Next
>      and then Select Command Prompt.
> 2. At the command prompt, launch regedit.exe and load the SYSTEM hive,
>      follow the below steps.
>
> a. Select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>
> b. On the File menu, select Load Hive.
>
> c. Browse to %WINDIR%\System32\Config
>   Folder and select “SYSTEM”
>
> d. Select Open.
>
> e. In the Load Hive dialog box, type
>   in “MySYSTEM” box for the registry
>   hive that you want to edit.
>
> 3. After the hive is loaded, modify the following key value per the
>      instructions below: You will need to
>      know what ControlSet the machine is
>      currently running on, this can be
>      determined by going to
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\MySYSTEM\Select and
>      find the “Current” value in the Right
>      hand side. (Example: Current value is
>      1 then the ControlSet will be
>      ControlSet001)
>
> Key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00X\Services\RpcSs
>   (X is the Number from the Current Key
>   from above)
>
> Value Name: ObjectName
>
> Old Value: LocalSystem
>
> New Value: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
>
> 4. Unload the SYSTEM hive by selecting the key “MySYSTEM” and then select
>      File -> Unload Hive… menu item.
> 5. Exit regedit.exe
> 6. Reboot the system normally

And from [Maximum PC Guides](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-vista/windows-vista-hangs-at-a-black-screen-when-booting-up/):

> Last Known Good Configuration
>
> I’m going to walk you through booting
>   Windows Vista using its last known
>   good configuration. Since Windows
>   Vista reverts to a previous version of
>   the registry, you might lose data that
>   was worked with since your last
>   successful boot.
>
> 1. Make sure your computer is powered down.
> 2. Turn your computer on and immediately start pressing F8 on your
>      keyboard repeatedly until you see a
>      black screen with white writing that
>      gives you a list of boot options.
> 3. Use the down arrow on your keyboard to select the Last Known Good
>      Configuration (Advanced) option.
> 4. Press Enter on your keyboard and cross your fingers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of my configurations already have the new value.

Comment: @George: What do you mean?  Is that stopping you from trying the last known good configuration?  Or is this your machines only ever configuration?

Comment: @John: There are only two configurations listed in the registry... and I have no clue where the second one came from.

Comment: @George: I would suggest trying whichever one you're not currently running.  (Assuming that you haven't yet.)

Comment: @John: How can I try it? All I have is a number in the registry.

Comment: @George: (1)turn off your machine. (2)Turn it on again and immediately start pressing F8 until you see a black screen with white writing that gives you a list of boot options. (3)Use the down arrow to select the Last Known Good Configuration (Advanced) option.  (4)Press enter and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall the old drivers first? Try booting into save mode and using windows restore to restore back the a previous point before the new drivers were installed. Or try rolling back the drivers...

Here is an unofficial work around that you might want to take a look at [here](http://www.prevx.com/blog/140/Black-Screen-woes-could-affect-millions-on-Windows--Vista-and-XP.html)

Comment: Yes, the old drivers were uninstalled first and I can boot into safe mode. The problem is that I still don't end up with a working driver.

Comment: Try to connect another monitor or try to reduce resolution (remember keyboard sequence to do that :)

Comment: @kokbira: Nope. Connecting another monitor does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be using the other display port as soon as you log in. Have you tried hooking up to the other port? You can also try logging into safe mode by pressing the f8 key durring startup. From there you might be able to play with graphics settings.

Comment: I can boot into safe mode no problem and it works fine. (Well, when I say fine, I mean that nothing happens that would be considered a problem in safe mode.)

Comment: @George Edison When you go into safe mode, open up the graphics settings and lower the resolution to the lowest possible and reboot. You can also try making a new user account to see if this blanks screen is specific to your account. If your graphics card is set up to use two monitors, switch it to use just one and make sure it is using the correct video port on the back of the computer. You should be able to do all this from safe mode.

Comment: @James: Okay... I never thought of changing the resolution. If I set the new resolution in Safe Mode, will this be the mode used during normal startup?

Comment: @George If i remember correctly, i was able to fix "Out of range" issues with the display by changing resolutions in safe mode. This unfortunately does not sound like the issue you are having. Based on your other comments, it is starting to sound more like malicious software that starts up with your computer. Taking out the hard drive and scanning it from another computer for viruses is one of the first things i do because it is easy to do. I'd also do a checkdisk for good measure (chkdsk /F). You should check the windows error logs in safe mode. Check the SMART status of the drive with hdtune

Comment: @George Also use autoruns from sysinternals to look at all the processes that start with your computer and look for suspicious ones. You can try a spybot search and destroy scan from safe mode. These are the standard things I do when computers do strange things.

Comment: @James: Okay, I ran `chkdsk /F` and no change. I disabled a number of startup applications. The SMART status of the drive is healthy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me had nothing to do with drivers or the OS. Both of my 8800 Ultras (SLI'd) died within a month of each other.

I started noticing weird artifacts, then would get a blue screen with an lsass.sys error. Eventually after logging in I would get the dreaded black screen.

I threw in another hard drive, fired up a new install of Windows 7, and had the same result with the newest NVIDIA drivers; booting into safe mode worked just fine. I tried all sorts of driver versions, nothing worked.

In the end, Google led me to some crazy dudes that were baking their video cards in the oven. I tried it. I kid you not, it worked!

Instead of paying $600 for another pair of 8800 Ultras, I brought them back to life by throwing them in the oven for 10 minutes at 385 degrees.

[Here's the exact method I used.](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1421792)

**Edit:** [here](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1542167) is a thread for your particular situation and [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1433887) is someone that successfully baked one.

**Edit 2:** There is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsmlALfEgPg) of some dudes showing you how to bake an HP.

Comment: Interesting... but don't forget that it works fine with OpenGL and with the samples from the DirectX SDK. I'm not quite convinced the card is defective yet.

Comment: Would a class action lawsuit against nvidia convince you? http://www.nvidiasettlement.com/affectedmodels.html

Comment: Hmmm... well, that might very well be the case if all other methods to get this working prove unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue a few months back.  I removed the battery and HDD and pressed and held the power button for 20 seconds.  Then insert the battery, HDD and power cable back and turned it on.  Seemed to worked for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some times a black out like this can happen even with other devices, my method in these cases has been disabling one by one certain integrated chips in BIOS, or BIOS feature (if is not a critical one!), and start each time to see if problem dissapears, to at least know which is causing it. In one occassion it would black out due to an integrated audio card in mother board, for example. In this way, I at least can know what (what drivers or faulty hardware,etc) I have to fight against. Just to add another idea.