# Why are Direct3D-based applications freezing when launched / closed?

Tags: windows-vista, freeze, nvidia-geforce, direct3d

Every time I start a game or application that uses DirectX (specifically Direct3D) in any way shape or form, the screen freezes for about 30-40 seconds. Everything then seems to work normally. The same thing will happen again when I quit the game.

This does not happen for OpenGL-based applications - only DirectX ones.

I am using Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit SP2 and my video card is an NVIDIA GeForce 8400M GS. I have the latest driver from NVIDIA (7.15.11.7432 A).

The PC itself is an [HP Pavillion dv6757ca](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01300306&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=ca&lang=en&product=3650205).

What could be causing this?

---

**Update:** I tried running Windows 8 (the developer preview) on the very same machine and... it works! The issue completely disappears. So I can only conclude that the problem was with Vista or the drivers since everything works fine now.

Comment: do you know, specifically, if all or just some versions of DirectX are having the issues? (such as, is it only DX9 or DX10 etc) hve you tried updating all versions of DirectX on your system (most likely just DX9 and DX10/10.1 in Vista)

Comment: @Xantec: Seems to be a problem with all versions of DirectX. I can try running the DirectX update tool to see if that helps at all.

Comment: Which version of drivers ?

Comment: @Sathya: The video card drivers? 7.15.11.7432 A - according to HP's website. I have no idea where they get that number from :)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Try the latest drivers http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-win7-winvista-260.99-whql-driver.html

Comment: @Xantec: Actually, I just tried one of the Direct3D 9 samples from the SDK and it worked fine. Weird...

Comment: @Sathya: But then I get [this](http://superuser.com/questions/219561/black-screen-after-logging-in-to-windows-vista).

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Weird. Have you been getting the freezes since day one ?

Comment: @Sathya: As far as I can remember... this was a 'feature' that came with the notebook. But it really hasn't been a problem until now.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Try removing existing drivers by using [Driver Sweeper](http://www.guru3d.com/category/driversweeper/) and re-install HP provided drivers. Wondering if this is hardware problem than a software one,

Comment: @Sathya: Don't forget that the card works just fine for OpenGL-based games. Also, the samples from the DirectX SDK seem to work fine. It's just every other commercial game that's doing this.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Yes I've read that - try running 3DMark '06 - does it give the same result ?

Comment: @Sathya: I'll try that - actually, is there something smaller I can download? The file is >500 MB.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison try [rthdribl (DX9)](http://www.daionet.gr.jp/~masa/rthdribl/) / [FurMark (OpenGL)](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/)

Comment: @Sathya: I tried `rthdribl` and as expected, it froze for about 30 seconds when I started it and for about 15 seconds when exiting. (It got about 30 FPS while running.)

Comment: @George and FurMark runs fine, I suppose. Did you have any success with updating DX  ? I'm sorry to say but I've no clue what's causing this.

Comment: @Sathya: Thanks for trying. I updated DirectX to the newest available version but still no luck.

Comment: @George Last ditch effort from my side: Rightclick on the desktop, click on Personalize , Display Settings, Advanced Settings,Troubleshoot tab -> Reduce h/w acceleration slider one notch at a time and see if that changes anything

Comment: @Sathya: I thought of that, but the troubleshoot tool is disabled thanks to the nVidia driver providing its own tool... and I already tried adjusting things in there.

Comment: @Sathya: This actually works on Win8 now - see my update.